# Creating a general pipe in Angular for dynamic mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-pipe

I have an Angular front-end which currently receives data from a REST API and shows it in a table. Received data is consisted of three different types: string, Date and number (both int and float).
Since there are multiple data columns and I would like to create a single table template for different types of received JSONs, I should create the mat-table dynamically:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z2" matSort matSortActive="sysTime"
        matSortDirection="desc" matSortDisableClear>
       
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of colDefs" [matColumnDef]="column.name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [hidden]="column.settings.hidden"
                (auxclick)="onHeaderClick($event, column)"> {{column.settings.alias}}
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [hidden]="column.settings.hidden"
                (click)="onRowClick(column.name, element)"> {{element[column.name] | generalPipe }} </td>
        </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="dataSource.columns$ | async; sticky:true; "></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: dataSource.columns$ | async;"></tr>
    </table>
```

The main problem is that some numbers are represented as strings. That is something at the backend and I can not change it. In order to sort the columns correctly I have to convert them to numbers.

Therefore I should have a general pipe to format numbers, strings and Dates respectively:

```
@Pipe({
    name: "generalPipe",
    pure: true
})
export class GeneralPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor() { }

    format = new DatePipe('en-US');
    intReg: RegExp = /^\d{1,10}$/;
    floatRef: RegExp = /^\d{1,4}\.\d{1,6}$/;
    public transform(value: any): any {

        if (Date.parse(value)) {

            return this.format.transform(value, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss');
        }

        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            if (this.intReg.test(value)) return parseInt(value);
            else if (this.floatRef.test(value)) return parseFloat(value);
        }
        return (value);

    }

}
```

Number formatting works but **Date** type evaluation does not work correctly. In some systems it parses the numeric value as Unix epoch and in some systems only formats the Date values.

I also tried checking *(value instanceof Date)* but again it does not work.

How can I fix this problem?

Sample JSON:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| sysTime | "2020-11-29T21:33:51" |
| number | "3435" |
| occurTime | "2040-12-12T12:56:13" |
| status | 1 |
| version | "1" |
| bat | 80 |
| latitude | 1.398401 |
| longtitude | 1.774052 |

Comment: Hi Iman , You said you want to convert them for example to number , pipe just convert it in template !!!

Comment: please provide sample data that you receive from backend.

Comment: @ArashHatami I added data sample!

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, I added another RegEx:

```
dateReg: RegExp = /^20\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/;
```

and then:

```
public transform(value: any): any {

        if (typeof value === 'string') {

            if (this.intReg.test(value)) return parseInt(value);
            else if (this.floatReg.test(value)) return parseFloat(value);
            else if (this.dateReg.test(value)) return this.dateFormat.transform(value, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss');
        }
        return (value);

    }
```

But I still don't know how to detect Date type.